# Starting an Spotify intent

Tags: android, android-intent, spotify, google-play

I want my app to open spotify links and send people to the app. If the app is installed, this works wonders:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("spotify:album:7rt7AxYexFTtdEqaJPekvX"));
```

However, there will be cases where the app is not installed yet, so I'll want them to download it from Google Play with this other intent:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spotify.mobile.android.ui"));
```

However, I really want it to be installed directly from Google Play instead of letting people to choose which app to open... if Google Play is installed. If Google Play is missing, I want them to choose which app to open (often it will be a navigator, but whatever)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I really want it to be installed directly from Google Play instead of letting people to choose which app to open

Use the `market://` `Uri` instead of the `https://` `Uri`: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

Also, please only use the `spotify:` scheme if that is publicly documented and supported.

Comment: @santirivera92: Until Spotify changes their app. Please only use the `spotify:` scheme if that is publicly documented and supported.

Comment: http://www.spotify.com/es/blog/archives/2008/01/14/linking-to-spotify/ It is. It's even constant for all Spotify apps.